# Is it possible to keep just one PP fees column but have two different formulas in there?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm building my first complex (for me) Spreadsheet and I'm really tripped up at one part. This is for keeping track of eBay sales.  I have a column for the "sold" price, eBay fees (9%), PayPal fee 2.9% +.30, and a "net profit" column....However, when I have an international sale PayPal charges 3.9% +.30.  Right now I have it so that when I enter in the sold price, the spreadsheet calculates the eBay fees, PP fees at 2.9% +.30, and gives me the net profit.  What can I do to make it calculate 3.9% +.30 for international sales?  I'd like to keep it as simple as possible and not add many more columns. Is it possible to keep just one PP fees column but have two different formulas in there? And then maybe have two different "sold" columns; one international, one domestic? I've been looking at this too long and probably overthinking it.

Answer (score 1):

It is simple to do what you want.

1. make a column that you specify either international or domestic.
2. Use an `IF(logical_expression, value_if_true, value_if_false)` statement

   - the logical expression to point to the international/domestic cell and compare it to the word international for example:  B2="international"
   - the value_if_true part is price * international rate
   - the value_if_false is the price * the domestic rate
3. the net profit would be the `sold price -minus the "ebayfee" cell - the "pp fee" cell`.